# Urban Airship integration error arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am trying  to integrate the Urban Airship SDK for push notifications I got this error when attempting to build the project.

> AirshipKit file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

The build settings in my own project included armv7 and arm64 architecture already as valid architectures (as seen in screen shot)

[image: build settings for the xcode project in question]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to change the build settings on the Urban Airship project. I was looking in the wrong place and scratching my head.

So if you go into the build settings for the Urban Airship project (which per Urban Airship's instructions should be at the top level of your existing project) you can see and adjust the build settings there to match the build settings in your own project. It was previous set to only be built for armv7 after updating this setting it build correctly.
[image: Urban Airship project build settings]